# NativeScript Angular Observable ListView does not display data

Tags: angular, typescript, nativescript

Have spent many hours just to get the data displayed from API to the ListView, no luck.

`_batches` is getting JSON from API, I have checked it using `console.log`, thus there is no error on JSON or the network side. Still, no data displayed in the `ListView`.

Everything is seen as `undefined`, checking this on emulator.

Using NS + Angular: All latest packages as of 30th Oct 2018

here is the important portion of code from component

```
import { Component, OnInit } from "@angular/core";
import { ObservableArray } from "data/observable-array";
import { Batch } from "../../shared/batch.model";
import { BatchesService } from "../../shared/batches.service";
import { finalize } from 'rxjs/operators';

@Component({
  selector: "ns-batches",
  moduleId: module.id,
  templateUrl: "./batches.component.html",
})

export class BatchesComponent implements OnInit {
  public _batches: ObservableArray < Batch > = new ObservableArray < Batch > ([]);

  constructor(private _batchesService: BatchesService) {}

  ngOnInit(): void {

    this._batchesService.load()
      .pipe(finalize(() => this._isLoading = false))
      .subscribe((batches: Array < Batch > ) => {
        this._batches = new ObservableArray(batches);
      });
  }
```

And this is the component html file

```
<StackLayout class="page">
  <ListView [items]="_batches" class="list-group" id="listBatches">
    <ng-template let-result="item">
      <GridLayout columns="100, *" rows="auto, auto,auto,auto" horizontalAlignment="left" verticalAlignment="top" backgroundColor="#CCCCCC">
        <img row="0" col="0" rowSpan="2" [src]="result.imageURL">
        <Label row="0" col="1" [nsRouterLink]="['/item', result.id]" [text]="'ID : ' + result.id" class="h3"></Label>
        <Label row="1" col="1" [text]="'Booked: ' + result.course" class="list-group-item"></Label>
        <Label row="2" col="1" [text]="'Oral: ' + result.oralconfirm" class="list-group-item"></Label>
        <Label row="3" col="0" colSpan="2" [text]="'Interested : ' + result.interested" class="list-group-item"></Label>
      </GridLayout>
    </ng-template>
  </ListView>
</StackLayout>
```

And this one is from service file

```
import { Injectable } from "@angular/core";

import { Http, Headers, Response, RequestOptions } from "@angular/http";
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders } from "@angular/common/http";
import { map } from "rxjs/operators";
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import {Component, NgZone} from '@angular/core';

import { Batch } from "./batch.model";

@Injectable()
export class BatchesService {

  private _batches = new Array < Batch > ();

  constructor(private http: Http) {}

  public load(): Observable < Batch[] > {
    return this.http.get('https://appspages.something.com/something/test')
      .pipe(map(res => res.json()));
  }
}
```

---

## Solved

Adding the solution to this problem,

Finally it worked !!
Problem was in the JSON. Here are the details -
My JSON structure was:

```
{
  "records": [{
      data of record 1
    },
    {
      data of record 2
    },
    {
      data of record 3
    },
    {
      data of record n
    }
  ]
}
```

I have to remove text

```
{
  "records":
```

from the beginning of the JSON and one `}` at the end.

This modified JSON worked well.

Not sure if there is a solution to render JSON as I have described above. If you know the solution for it, please post below.

Sidd, thanks a lot for helping out!
You are amazing!

Comment: Which Angular version are you using?

Comment: Angular Version is 7.0.2

Comment: Please move your solution to an answer of its own, thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the docs of [ListView](https://docs.nativescript.org/angular/ui/ng-ui-widgets/listview) `items` property requires an array instead of an Observable array.

`this._batches = batches;` should do it. You don't need `this._batches = new ObservableArray(batches);`

```
import { Component, OnInit } from "@angular/core";
import { ObservableArray } from "data/observable-array";
import { Batch } from "../../shared/batch.model";
import { BatchesService } from "../../shared/batches.service";
import { finalize } from 'rxjs/operators';

@Component({
  selector: "ns-batches",
  moduleId: module.id,
  templateUrl: "./batches.component.html",
})

export class BatchesComponent implements OnInit {
  public _batches: Batch[];

  constructor(private _batchesService: BatchesService) {}

  ngOnInit(): void {

    this._batchesService.load()
      .pipe(finalize(() => this._isLoading = false))
      .subscribe((batches: Batch[]) => {
        this._batches = batches;
      });
  }
```

Also, you should be using `HttpClient` instead of `Http` to not have to call `.json` in `.map` in your BatchesService:

```
import { Injectable } from "@angular/core";
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders } from "@angular/common/http";
import { map } from "rxjs/operators";
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { Component, NgZone } from '@angular/core';
import { Batch } from "./batch.model";

@Injectable()
export class BatchesService {

  private _batches = new Array<Batch>();

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}

  public load(): Observable<Batch[]> {
    return this.http
      .get<Batch[]>('https://appspages.something.com/something/test');
  }
}
```

Here's a [**NativeScript Playground Sample**](https://play.nativescript.org/?template=play-ng&id=ctWTiZ) for your ref.

#### UPDATE:

In your template, you could simply do this to work with the data that you're getting:

```
<ListView [items]="_batches.records" class="list-group" id="listBatches">
```

Comment: The suggested change generates error for this._batches, error says : Type 'Batch[]' is not assignable to type 'ObservableArray<Batch>

Comment: Sidd, thank you for helping me, tried this too but no luck.

Comment: do you think Observable from these lines in service is creating problem, we have used simple arrays elsewhere now

public load(): Observable<Batch[]> {

Comment: No errors since 14 Hours. LoL, But no data seen in Label. I am using emulator. Wherever variables are assigned in [text] for <Label>, the result is "undefined"

Comment: One strange behavior observed. API returns JSON having 3 courses and its details, where as the emulator is rendering 8 courses.

Comment: Guess you guys got it working, but still for the record `ObservableArray` also works.

Comment: Finally it worked !! 
Problem was in the JSON. Here are the details -
My JSON structure was : 
{
"records":
[
{ data of record 1 },
{ data of record 2 },
{ data of record 3 },
{ data of record n }
]
}

I have to remove text 
{
"records":
from beginning of the JSON and one } at the end.

This modified JSON worked well. 

Not sure if there is a solution to render JSON as I have described above.

Sidd, thanks a lot for helping out !!!!!
You are amazing !!!

Comment: I tried your update about _batches.records but it returns undefined in <Label>

Due to limitation in characters count comments, I pasted just portion on JSON showing one dataset.
Here is my Json : 
{  
   "records":[  
      {  
         "id":1,
         "course":"Chocolate Making",
         "imageURL":"https:\/\/something.com\/storage\/courses\/imagefolder\/snap-medium.jpg",
         "batchdatetime":"1st Nov 2018 10am to 2pm",
         "batchvenue":"Headoffice",
         "paid":8,
         "oralconfirm":2,
         "interested":120
      }
   ]
}